# VBA : Need advice to speed up loop and recordset function

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue to run more than 10K data and that will take a long time to finish the code... Any advice to shorten and speed up loop and record set function? Sorry for my beginner level code... My code as below :

```
x = 1
Do
    'Start connect to SQL
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\BCAPP;Database=MVS;Uid=mvs;Pwd=mvs;"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(12, 12) <> "" And Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value Like "E*" Then
        sSQLSting = "SELECT *FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process_details] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "' and scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N'"
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value = "E" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value
        sSQLSting = "SELECT *FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process_details] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "' and scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N'"
    End If

    'Paste SQL table
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
    If Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18) = "" Then
        Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    End If
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close

    x = x + 1
Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = ""

x = 1
Do
    'Start connect to SQL
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\BCAPP;Database=MVS;Uid=mvs;Pwd=mvs;"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(12, 12) <> "" Then
        sSQLSting = "SELECT TOP 1 scan_qty FROM [MVS].[dbo].[KITTING_Details] where scan_lotno = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 23) & "'"
    End If

    'Paste SQL table
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
    Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 31).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close

    x = x + 1
Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19) = ""

x = 1
y = 1
Do
    If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(y, 19) Then
        Do
            Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 17) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Data").Cells(y, 31), Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 17))
            y = y + 1
        Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) <> Sheets("Data").Cells(y, 19)
        x = x + 1
    ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value <> Sheets("Data").Cells(y, 19) Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = ""

x = 1
Do
    'Start connect to SQL
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\BCAPP;Database=MVS;Uid=mvs;Pwd=mvs;"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(12, 12) <> "" Then
        sSQLSting = "SELECT pos_qty, foil_anode_std FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "'"
    End If

    'Paste SQL table
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
    Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 33).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close
    x = x + 1
Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19) = ""

lastrow = Sheets("Data").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 35).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 35).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("AI1:AI" & lastrow)
Sheets("Data").Range("AI1:AI" & lastrow).Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("AI1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you write and read a lot of data to worksheets, which is very slow.
Dont dump the recordsets to sheets, rather dump them to arrays, and process the data from there.

Recordset to array example:

```
Dim ReturnArray

Paste SQL table
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
ReturnArray = mrs.GetRows
mrs.Close
```

If you cant rewrite the code or speed is not that important, then turnoff screenupdateing, calculations and events at the start of your macro and at the end turn them back on, this will help quite a bit as well.

```
'Turning them off
Application.Screenupdating =False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Your code
'Turning them oN
Application.Screenupdating =True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Hi Coffegrinder, thanks for fast respond... Can you give me one example of using recordset to array based on one of my code below, because I have no idea to do it and I don't know what to begin with... Thanks...

Comment: Hy, I edited my answer. But first, try to turn off screenupdating, calculations and events at the start of your macro, see if it's helps.